# How to copy files from one directory to another after closing the Dolphin file manager in Kubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 16.04, filemanager, dolphin

Please, I need your help with the following:

**The Problem:** I can't copy/move one file (or more) from one directory to another unless if both directories are opened using the file manager. In other words, if I closed the file manager after copying the files from the first directory, the system clears out the copied files and thus stopping me from pasting them into the other directory. By closing the file manager, I mean closing the instance of the file manager that is displaying the files and not terminating the process of the file manager (i.e. the file manager process is still running).

**System Details:**

[image]

**File Manager:**

Dolphin File Manager Version 15.12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this topic, it seems that the problem was related to my clipboard manager itself. My clipboard manager was not running at all.

Make sure to set your clipboard manager to autorun with your OS.
In Kubuntu, the recommended clipboard manager is "Klipper".